# PHP Calendar - How to make it send an email notification for new events?

Tags: php, email, calendar, notifications, ugc

I'm using http://phpcodeworks.com/pec/index for a nice User Generated Calendar but it doesn't have the function of sending an email to me when someone posts an event. I'd really like this feature and I really like this calendar.

It's all open source, so you'll be able to play with the code and look at it all.

Comment: We're not here to do work for you. We're here if you're attempting to do something yourself and get caught up on something. Your last statement alone makes this type of thing more appropriate for rentacoder.com or some other freelance developer.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the [mail](http://php.net/mail) function inside whichever bit of the code handles the creation of new events.